# Syntax to move backwards in LinkedList?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

i know that LinkedLists are implemented in a doubly linked way, so each node has a next and a previous pointer. however, i couldn't find what syntax to use to access the previous nodes?
i looked on the java api, and there is a method to iterate through a linkedlist backwards. 
that to me, implies that there is an easy way to access previous nodes P:.

i am trying to design an experiment to prove that LinkedLists isn't just a singlely linked list but i can't think of how to do so without moving backwards in linkedlists.

please explain to  me how to move backwards if it is possible, thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand your question. First you say that you found a way to move backwards by looking at the javadoc, and then you ask how to move backwards. So, what's your question exactly?

Comment: i think it is possible to move backwards because of the descending iterator. but i don't know how to use the same function in junit tests. 
so for example, if there was a list of 1-> 2-> 3, i want to know how to call the previous node from the 2.

Comment: Take a look at the source (there should be a `src.zip` in your Java directory): The `LinkedList` is made up of `Node`s that have a `prev` reference, which is also used by the `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LinkedList` has a `listIterator(int)` method. So you can use:

```
// Start at the end...
ListIterator<Foo> iterator = list.listIterator(list.size());
while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
    Foo foo = iterator.previous();
}
```

That doesn't *prove* that it's a doubly-linked list - that could be implemented very inefficiently in a single-linked list, for example - but that's how I'd go about iterating over a linked list backwards.

Comment: thank you very much :)
how would i prove that it is a doubly linked list ? if being able to move backwards isn't sufficient to prove

Comment: @user1476390: by looking at the javadoc, or at the source code.

Comment: @JBNizet, i know the documentation says it is a doubly linked list, but my assignment is to verify the claim somehow and i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @user1476390: Well, you could plot "time taken to iterate backwards" against "size of list" - for a doubly-linked list that graph should be linear.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [LinkedList.listIterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int)) which will return an iterator that you can use to go both directions (next/previous)